# update_post_meta breaking wp_update_nav_menu_item

Tags: menus, post-meta

So i want to automatically add random words to my menu items after i save their parent menu at **Appareance -> Menus**

I'm using `wp_update_nav_menu` action for this:

```
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'my_custom_update_nav_menu' );
function my_custom_update_nav_menu( $menu_id ) {
   $nav_menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_id );
   foreach( $nav_menu_items as $nav_menu_item ) {
      // Here goes some code to skip current nav menu if was already processed in the past, and some code to grab $random_word;
      $data = array( 'menu-item-title' => $nav_menu_item->title . ' ' . $random_word );
      wp_update_nav_menu_item( $menu_id, $nav_menu_item->ID, $data );
      update_post_meta( $nav_menu_item->ID, '_nmik_keyword', $random_word );
   }
}
```

The post meta is being added into wp_postmeta table, however the nav menu item title isn't updated! But, if i comment out this line:

```
// update_post_meta( $nav_menu_item->ID, '_nmik_keyword', $random_word );
```

The nav menu item title is updated! How come `update_post_meta` is interfering with `wp_update_nav_menu_item` in this incredible way?

Comment: It would probably be easier to do this whenever the menu is being displayed - is that an option in your usecase?

Comment: Considered that as an option before, but no longer!

Comment: Where are you getting `$menu_item` from? Should that be `$nav_menu_item`?

Comment: Yes, a typo,  $menu_item = $nav_menu_item;